# LibGdx: Neither delta or raw delta time corresponds to the time between calls to render()

Tags: libgdx, render, delta

I am using tweens in LibGdx and I use delta to update.

If I count ms (with System.currentTimeMillis) between calls to render I get around 16ms on my Android phone. When I log that time vs delta time I get different values. Sometimes delta is like 4000ms and sometimes 16ms. This also occurrs for raw delta time. It totally screws up my tween animation, although I don't see the same behaviour on the Desktop application. Can anyone explain this behaviour? If I go with System.currentTimeMillis I get consistent nice tween animations...

Comment: Please provide the actual time measuring code sample. Are you measuring time between frames by `com.badlogic.gdx.Graphics#getDeltaTime()` ?

Comment: Screen#render(float delta) is what I use, and where I measure.

Comment: You are seeing 4 second hiccups in your game?